# What is the QGIS 2.2 print layout map extent CRS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.2, pyqgis

I have project in ESPG:4326 with 2 layers (both in 4326), and map print layout.
I've chosen current extent for layout map. Map is centered and prints as I expect.

Next, I access this object via python console

```
iface.activeComposers()[0].composition().getComposerMapById(0).extent()
```

And it's not in 4326. For Carlsruhe GE I've got

`POLYGON((
932814.23699999996460974 6276112.49500000011175871, 
934971.30599999998230487 6276112.49500000011175871, 
934971.30599999998230487 6277610.67700000014156103, 
932814.23699999996460974 6277610.67700000014156103, 
932814.23699999996460974 6276112.49500000011175871))`

How could I get CRS of print layout map object extent?

Comment: The polygon looks like EPSG:3857. Are you using the Openlayers plugin?

Comment: I use gdal wms source with osm tms. http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-users/2010-July/066061.html Source is in 3857, but and as I understand GDAL reproject tiles to show them in 4326 project. Yes it seems to be 3857 but how can I get it using python api?